# Boxed and align

Tags: align, boxes, mathjax

**Remark**: The examples in this post are not the real cases, the real one is a web page using MathJax. It seems MathJax has some restrictions about the packages that can be used. In particular, `mathtools` seems to not be supported.

The following document fails with errors "Missing `}`"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \boxed{ 2x+y & = 11 } \\
  3x & = 19 - 2y
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be the usage of `\boxed` (if it is removed, the error disappears) inside an align block.

Any solution of this issue or other way to enclose an equation or some terms of an equation when using align blocks?

Note the following doesn't causes any error:

```
\begin{align}
 \boxed{ 2x+y } & = 11 \\
  3x & = 19 - 2y
\end{align}
```

Comment: `\boxed` hides the `&` from the parser. Try the similar command `\Aboxed` from the `mathtools ` package

Comment: You have discovered that MathJax is not LaTeX: it doesn't understand LaTeX commands the same as LaTeX does. If a feature is not supported in MathJax, there's little one can do on the language side.

Comment: @egreg: A comment absolutely improductive. In fact, the main problem is enclose anything with brackets inside an align. Secondary is that usual alternatives are not applicable when using MathJax

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Why? You don't seem to know that the two systems are *very* different from each other. For instance, it's not that MathJax supports `amsmath`: the developers of MathJax have implemented *some* of the features of `amsmath`, but not all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a workaround that works with MathJax, but it's not pretty and might need additional tweaking depending on the MathJax implementation you're working with:

```
$$ 
\begin{align*}
2x+y &= 11 \\ 
3x &= 19 - 2y 
\; \llap{\mathrel{\boxed{\phantom{3x = 19 - 2y}}}}
\end{align*} 
$$
```

Here's what this would look like on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com):

[image]

**Edit**: I boxed the wrong line by mistake, but one can accomplish the same thing for any line within an `align` block.

Comment: It preferible to use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to. Good LaTeX

Answer (score 45):

`\boxed` cannot contain alignment points. Load  `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case) and use `\Aboxed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \Aboxed{ 2x+y & = 11 } \\
  3x & = 19 - 2y
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution. Unfortunately, this code is in the real case inside a www page using Mathjax, and mathjax doesn't supports this mathtools package.

Comment: `\Aboxed` is the "correct" way to box an equation in the `align` environment. If it's not supported by mathjax, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tikz` to create frame

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner ysep=0pt,anchor=base](#1){\strut};}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \tikzmark{A}2x+y & = 11 \tikzmark{B} \\
                3x & = 19 - 2y
\end{align}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw(A.south west)rectangle(B.north east);

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, not supported by MathJax.