# Cross out a multiline expression inside an align* environment

Tags: align, cancel

I'd like to cross out a subsection of an aligned environment, as below (the actual content doesn't matter).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
4h + b &= \lambda 2bh \\
4 \cancel{b} &= \lambda b^{\cancel{2}} && \quad \text{for } b \neq 0\\
b ^{2}h - V &= 0\\
\\
% cross out this section
b &= \frac{4}{\lambda}\\
4h + \frac{4}{\lambda} &= 2\cancel{\lambda} h \frac{4}{\cancel{\lambda} }\\
4 \lambda h+ 4 &= 8 \lambda h\\
4 \lambda h &= 4\\
\lambda h &= 1
% end the crossed out section
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I tried relative stacking on a phantom copy of the math (as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500751/238240)), but it seems like `\llap` only stacks up one line. I really have no idea what I'm doing, but I hope there's a solution that doesn't involve something too heavy like `tikz`. Something like [the `\Aboxed` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346578/238240) to the same issue with `boxed` would be incredible.

The thing I tried:
[image: llap only overlaps one line up]

```latex
\begin{align*}
4h + b &= \lambda 2bh \\
4 \cancel{b} &= \lambda b^{\cancel{2}} && \quad \text{for } b \neq 0\\
b ^{2}h - V &= 0\\\\

% cross out this section
b &= \frac{4}{\lambda}\\
4h + \frac{4}{\lambda} &= 2\cancel{\lambda} h \frac{4}{\cancel{\lambda} }\\
4 \lambda h+ 4 &= 8 \lambda h\\
4 \lambda h &= 4\\
\lambda h &= 1
% end the crossed out section
% the code to generate a phantom cross out 
\; \llap{\mathrel{\xcancel{\phantom{\begin{align*}
b = \frac{4}{\lambda}\\
4h + \frac{4}{\lambda} = 2\cancel{\lambda} h \frac{4}{\cancel{\lambda} }\\
4 \lambda h+ 4 = 8 \lambda h\\
4 \lambda h = 4\\
\lambda h = 1\\
\end{align*}}}}}
\end{align*}
```